# updating URL in edit text

Tags: android, url, webclient

I want to update my url when a page starts loading in `OnPageStarted()` but when I run these code

```
public class web_client extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        EditText editText=view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        editText.setText(url);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
03-10 12:05:35.022 3385-3385/com.example.mmalishant.mvd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.example.mmalishant.mvd, PID: 3385
      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
      at com.example.mmalishant.mvd.web_client.onPageStarted(web_client.java:35)
      at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageStarted(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:517)
      at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClientCallbackHelper$MyHandler.handleMessage(AwContentsClientCallbackHelper.java:144)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
      03-10 12:05:35.585 1269-1269/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1269: eglCreateSyncKHR(1669): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

Comment: edit text is not inside your webview. Use the view reference of your activity

Comment: Can you please share your layout design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the `view` you have used in

`EditText editText=view.findViewById(R.id.edit);`

is the `WebView` from the method. I am sure there can not be an `EditText` within your `WebView`.

The solution is you should `findViewById` in your Activity's or Fragment's rootView.

*UPDATE:*

Since the `WebViewClient` is found in another Class and file then this will work:

```
EditText editText=((YourActivityClassName)view.getContext()).findViewById(R.id.edit);
```

Comment: yaa but onpagestarted is in a different class and the view i am looking for is in main activity...what should i do

Comment: There is no problem there! First tell me is this class `web_client` inside your activity as an inner class? or it is just a completely another file? @IshantTiwari

Comment: its completly a differnet file

Comment: Okay do this `EditText editText=((YourActivityClassName)view.getContext()).findViewById(R.id.edit);` instead!